# HTML site with PostgreSQL database (Bitnami Wappstack)

Tags: php, html, mysql, postgresql, bitnami

i'm a bit stuck with an university project I have to deliver in a week.
I have to create a small "library" website with a database containing users, books, authors and whatsoever.
The fact is, we've been taught how to create databases but not how to create sites using HTML and PHP, therefore I literaly know nothing.
I have downloades Bitnami Wappstack which I've been told is a good and simple tool for what I have to do.
So far, I've created the database using PhpAgAdmin (or something like that), now I'm studying HTML.
So here come my questions:

- The user and administrator privileges must be coded on the website or using php pages?
- Where can I find good tutorials for php which can teach me how to "connect" the html pages to my database? (i don't want to learn everything of PHP, only the things I need right now)
- Where am I supposed to save my files inside the Wappstack folder?

Thank you all!

Comment: [This guide here](http://www.w3resource.com/PostgreSQL/PostgreSQL-with-php-a-through-introduction.php)
will probably be your best bet. This is not the place for Tutorial questions.

Comment: This question should probably be splitted into multiple questions - see http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/39223/one-post-with-multiple-questions-or-multiple-posts And yeah, this is a place for quetions about specific problems rather than tutorials.

Comment: With the exception of the second question (where I actually asked for a tutorial, and Panama Jack linked me to one) the other 2 are small questions, and in particular the first one should be easy to answer to